# List of objects to List<string[]>

Tags: c#, casting

Is is possible to  cast/transfer value of list of objects to list of array strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, actually i tried to do this but didnt succeed

Comment: No sorry. your question is missing at least the minimum amount of informations to help you. Where is code? How are object build? What have you tried? What are the errors you are getting? So do you go to the doctor and say: 'I am ill, help me.' ? Or do you go to the doctor with the most information about your illness as possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases and it is pretty unclear which one you need:

*First case*: You have a list of actual `string`s stored in a list of `object`.
You can use LINQ `Cast` function which will cast all objects to another type:

```
List<object> objs = new List<object>();
List<string> strs = objs.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

It will **cast** every `object` to a `string`.

*Second case*: You have a list of `object`s (not `string`s or not only `string`s) and you need to cast it to strings.
You can use `object.ToString` function and LINQ `Select` function:

```
List<string> objs = new List<object>();
List<string> strs = objs.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

It will **apply `ToString()` function** to every `object` which will produce `string`s.
However, some types can have a poor `ToString()` definition or cause an unexpected behaviour (for example, just output class name).

Moreover, the second case covers the first one. I mean, **you can use the second approach in both cases** as `string.ToString()` returns the same string.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if the list contains non-strings as well, `OfType` is a safer approach.

Comment: Also I think he wanted a  `List<string[]>`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, actually i've tried to interpret the code in this way. is this right ?

foreach (var str in orderItem.SupportedPaymentTypeList)
   {
    _tempSupportedPaymentTypeArray[0] = str.CompanyCode;
    _tempSupportedPaymentTypeArray[1] = str.PaymentTypeCode;
    _tempSupportedPaymentTypeArray[2] = str.PaymentCategory.ToString();
    _tempSupportedPaymentTypeList.Add(_tempSupportedPaymentTypeArray);
    _tempSupportedPaymentTypeList = new List<String[]>();
   }

Comment: As I am interpreting his question-title correctly he wants a list of string arrays. Not just a list of strings. But as I mentioned in my OP-comment, answering his question is a bit fuzzy work her.

Comment: Actually my real problem here is i need to cast an object to a primitive type (List<string[]>) to avoid backward compatibility issue in serialization and deserialization

Comment: In case OP needs to cast `List<object>` to `List<string[]>` but not with `objs.Cast<string[]>.ToList()` - we need more details. What is stored in this array and why is it `List<object>` etc.